# Does there exist a hash-table in C++ (pre-C++11)?

Tags: c++, hashtable

I'm looking for something that implements a hash table in the manner that most textbooks explain it, with constant time insertion/deletion/search. I know about std::unordered_map, but I'm looking for something that works without C++11. I know how to create the class from scratch, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: `std::tr1::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 4):

The [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) library is the way to go. Many of Boost's founders are on the C++ standards committee and libraries/APIs from Boost often make their way into the standard.

[`boost::unordered_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html) would be what you want. Its API is very similar to C++11's `std::unordered_map`. The underlying representation is a bucketed hash table (much like `unordered_map`).

Answer (score 0):

Before c++11, hashing is not a part of c++ standard, but most STL implement `hash_set` and `hash_map`. You can use them by simply including their header files. But firstly you must make sure your compiler supports it.